# Fixing version conflicts in Android studio

Tags: android

So I connected my app to `Firebase`, and they gave me this:

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 16.0.0.

Although this may sound weird, but i don't fully understand what they mean. This is my gradle code:

```
dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
        core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Can someone please explain to me what the error message means and what I can do? How do i update this google.android.gms?

Help will be appreciated :-)

Comment: Is this de only build.gradle file in your whole project? Do a project search, there should be another one. In your root folder.

Comment: This is my dependencies part of the gradle file. I didnt post the whole thing, it was unnecessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the same version like, if firebasecore is 16.0.0
all other firebase should be the same 16.0.0

please correct this..in your app gradle :

```
   { compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'}

use it like this....

    implementation  'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.0'

Let me know it this work for u...
```

Answer (score 0):

u should use same version otherwise it will conflict with other same support lib